# Rewrite rules for Drupal Boost with Lighttpd

Tags: http, lighttpd, drupal

I have been given the super task of preparing a web site to get hammered....

Or site is drupal based, I have found what could be my answer in the form of Boost. But I can't for the life of me find any information on the Lighttpd rewrite rules to make it function.

All suggestion welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some rules for it that where fairly close; and with some help on the issue queue we have a good set of rules now.
http://drupal.org/node/150909#comment-2353894

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an [issue on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/150909) for this but I take it you'd found it ....

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this question, I ended up having to write lua script to make this work. But no it does it works perfectly. Let me know if anyone wants it.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post it to the discussion thread mentioned above we can all look at it and perhaps improve it for the community.

Then hopefully get it submitted as part of the Boost archive.